# How to subtract a negative number in C#?

Tags: c#, parsing, numbers

[image]

If I subtract a positive number from a positive number, the code works.

For example, `4-1=3`.
The problem is when I subtract a negative number, like `3 - -2`.

This should equal `5`.

When i enter the '-' in textbox txt_p7 (second textbox),
it shows an error at this code:

```
txt_result.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(txt_p1.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(txt_p7.Text)).ToString();
```

Here is the code I'm using:

```
private void txt_p1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_p1.Text)) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_p7.Text)))

txt_result.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(txt_p1.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(txt_p7.Text)).ToString();

    }

private void txt_p7_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_p1.Text)) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_p7.Text)))


            txt_result.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(txt_p1.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(txt_p7.Text)).ToString();
    }
```

Comment: What is the error message ??

Comment: The first step in correcting an error is *reading the error message*.

Comment: FormatException was unhandled .. 

at the first time i key in the value , no1 = -3 , no2 = 4 ,the result show = -7..
that ok , after that , i change the value no1 or no2 , have error ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is in `txt_p7_TextChanged()`

Hence when you tried to input a "-", before you input any number, this method is called.

`Convert.ToInt32(txt_p7.Text)` will throw an error as `txt_p7.Text = "-"` at this point of time is not a number.

Put a break point at the beginning of `txt_p7_TextChanged()` and you will see what is wrong.

Try this

```
    private void txt_p7_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int number1, number2;
        if (int.TryParse(txt_p1.Text, out number1) && int.TryParse(txt_p7.Text, out number2))
            txt_result.Text = (number1 - number2).ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Without the error message, it is hard to tell what is happening, but from what I can see you are triggering a calculation before the number has been completed.

If you input a value into txt_p1, and attempt to input a negative value into txt_p7, entering '-' will trigger a calculation as the if conditional is satisfied due to both textboxes containing a string. The problem is you are converting to integer without any error checking, so it is trying to convert '-' into an integer which is causing your fail.

```
private void txt_p1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_p1.Text)) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_p7.Text)))
        {
            int val1, val2;
            //Ensure both are valid integers
            if (int.TryParse(txt_p1.Text, out val1) && int.TryParse(txt_p7.Text, out val2))
            {
                txt_result.Text = (val1 - val2).ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

You need validate the input prior to conversion else non-numerical characters can be entered which will cause an run-time failure.

Comment: Sir .. i make it clear.. i want to minus txt_p1 with txt_p7..

( txt_p1 - txt_p7) ... Now the error is at txt_p7.. when i insert negative value at txt_p7 , it have error.. but if txt_p7 is positive value , it worked.. very weird , because txt_p1 its okay to input the negative value ..

Comment: It is fine in p1 as there is currently no input into p7. That means that both textboxes are not populated therefore your null checks are saying "p7 is null, don't try and convert". If you input a number into p7 first, and then input a negative into p1, you will encounter the same error.